# Button text swapping on clicking any 2 buttons with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are five buttons:

```
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
<button id="btn5">5</button>
```

**What Have To Be Done:**

When clicking on any two buttons, the texts should swap between those buttons.

*For example:* If we click on "#btn1" and then on "#btn3", the text of "#btn1" should become "3" and the text of "#btn3" should become "1".

The above mentioned process should work on every buttons like clicking on the first button and the fifth button and so on.

**Question:** How can we do this with JQuery?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

Set a `data-flag` attribute to the button which has been clicked and remove when the corresponding toggle `button` is clicked.

```
$( "button" ).click( function(){
   if ( $("button[data-flag]").length > 0 ) //already clicked a button
   {
      var id = $("button[data-flag]").attr( "data-flag" );
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text( $( "#" + id ).text());
      $( "#" + id ).text( text );
      $("button[data-flag]").removeAttr( "data-flag" ); //remove this line if toggling shouldn't clear
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).attr( "data-flag", this.id );
   }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$( "button" ).click( function(){
   if ( $("button[data-flag]").length > 0 ) //already clicked a button
   {
      var id = $("button[data-flag]").attr( "data-flag" );
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text( $( "#" + id ).text());
      $( "#" + id ).text( text );
      $("button[data-flag]").removeAttr( "data-flag" );
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).attr( "data-flag", this.id );
   }
});
```

```css
button[data-flag]
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
<button id="btn5">5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class to identify which button should be swapped. That way you could apply some css to visually identify the button too. Also, this uses existing properties, rather than creating new variables.

css:

```
.swap { color: green; }
```

javscript:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if ($('button.swap').length) {
    $(this).val(this.textContent).text($('button.swap').val());
    $('button.swap').text(this.value).removeClass('swap').val('');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('swap').val(this.textContent);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpy08krd/

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** - This is if you want to create a pair which swaps and resets on each 2nd click.
https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/4skgd2a6/

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if (!($('button').hasClass('first'))) {
    $(this).addClass('first');
  } else {
    let thisText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text($('button.first').text());
    $('button.first').text(thisText).removeClass('first');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
```

**Option 2** - This option is if you want to swap on each click, no resetting between pairs.
https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/vw304u2x/

```js
var gLastText = '';
var gLastButton;
$('button').click(function() {
  if (gLastText !== '') {
    var thisText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(gLastText);
    $('#' + gLastButton).text(thisText);
  }
  gLastText = $(this).text();
  gLastButton = $(this).attr('id');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
<button id="btn5">5</button>
```